# Weird espresso leak Delonghi Perfecta ESAM5600SL

Tags: espresso-machine, maintenance, bean-to-cup

I got a used Delonghi Perfecta machine. It's the first espresso machine I have had so I still don't know much about them, I got it a week ago and it was working fine until this morning when it started leaking from the back of the espresso nozzle.

This started right after I opened it for the first time and cleaned out the grounds container. Could this be a simple issue where something inside the machine is just misplaced from when I closed it up or should I contact a professional services take a look and fix it?

Thank you all kindly :)
[image: Leak]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally someone recommended descaling, the pipes were blocked which was causing everything to leak out. Descaling the machine took care of it!